# Probability of ball-drawing-game for two players

Tags: probability

Two players $A$ and $B$ take turns to draw a ball with replacement from a bag containing $a$ white balls and $b$ black balls. Player $A$ draws a ball first, it will be player $B$'s turn next if a black ball is drawn, otherwise, player $A$ gets a second draw with a chance of winning the game if a white ball is drawn immediately again after the first. The same rule applies when player B takes his or her turn. Determine $p_A$ and $p_B$ the probabilities that eventually player $A$ and $B$, respectively, wins the game in terms of $a$ and $b$.

How can I solve this problem without using Markov Chain?

Comment: What have you tried?  Are the draws with or without replacement?

Comment: You know how to solve it using Markov chains/first step analysis, and are seeking some other method ?

Comment: Compute the probability $q= \left( \frac {a}{a+b} \right )^2$ that Player $A$ wins *on the first turn*.  Then $p_B=(1-q)p_A$ (do you see why?) and $p_A+p_B=1$.  Use these two equations to solve for $p_A= \frac{1}{2-q}$ and $p_B=\frac{1-q}{2-q}$.

Comment: why $p_A=\frac{1}{2-q}$ and $p_B=\frac{1-q}{2-q}$?

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit sad that **odds** are often treated as synonymous to **probability** (which they aren't) and not used in the proper sense when they could simplify computations.

Let $p= \frac{a}{a+b}$

$A$ either wins on first turn with probability = $p^2$,
or passes it on to $B$ with probability  $(1-p^2)$

P(B wins on first turn) = $(1-p^2)p^2$,
**and if not, we are back to square 1**

Thus **odds** of $A$ winning $={p^2}:[p^2(1-p^2)] = 1:(1-p^2)$

And **probability** of $A$ winning $= \frac{1}{1+1-p^2} = \frac{1}{2-p^2}$

You can now compute the probability of $B$ winning, and transform both results in the form specified in the question.

Comment: what is 
square 1**?

Comment: No one has won, and  A  is to toss, so back to where one started, with no progress having been made.